# N-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction in C#

Tags: c#, math.net

I want to calculate chi square and p-value for proportions equality.

I would prefer to use standard library like math.net but not sure how to do it using documentation https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/ChiSquared.htm.

In R, it is straight forward by,

prop.test(c(10,20,15), c(40,70,55))

```
3-sample test for equality of proportions without
continuity correction
```

data:  c(10, 20, 15) out of c(40, 70, 55)
X-squared = 0.16369, df = 2, p-value = 0.9214